# #include <cmath> : "In FIle included from" error message?

Tags: c++, linux, netbeans, include

I want to use `<cmath>`. If I do:

```
#include <cmath>
```

I get the error message:

> "In File included from"

However, when I type `<cma` and do ctrl+spacebar (in Netbeans) it shows me all the files available and `cmath` is listed (its in /usr/include/c++/4.7). I dont understand why the GUI editor/intellisense knows the `cmath` header exists, but I have the error "In File included from"?

Full error message:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/cmath:46:0,
                 from ../../Documents/FD/MyFile.h:4,
                 from ../../Documents/FD/MyFIle.cpp:1:
/opt/intel/include/math.h:27:3: error: #error "This Intel <math.h> is for use with only the Intel compilers!"
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/_ext/2009285305/MyFile.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/me/NetBeansProjects/Project'
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/me/NetBeansProjects/Project'
```

These are my include directories:

> /opt/intel/include;
>
> /usr/include/boost;
>
> /usr/include

EDIT (For Chris):

```
#ifndef MYFILE_H
#define MYFILE_H

#include <cmath>


class MyFile{
    public:
        static double doesntmatter(double x, int y, double z);

    private:
};

#endif
```

Comment: That's not a complete error message. It also applies to a specific area of code, which needs to be shown (preferably in the form of an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)).

Comment: As you can see from my edit- there wasn't really much point in a SSCCE, as I had already mentioned the useful information in my post (the include directories I have etc).

Comment: Have added the compile error - its something to do with the fact <cmath> uses math.h and Intel also have a math.h library

Comment: Do not include the directory `/opt/intel/include`. It is for intel compilers, not gcc

Comment: @TomásBadan I know that would fix it, but I want to use the Intel header <ia32intrinsic.h> in my project?

Comment: Suggest to use a intel compiler instead

Comment: If using GCC, compile with `g++ -Wall -H` to understand the actual included files! So try `make CXX='g++ -Wall -H'` or `make CXXFLAGS='-Wall -H'`; and don't use `/opt/intel/include` with GCC!

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans is aware of several standard library headers, but this does not guarantee that your path has been correctly configured.  Check to insure that your path is correctly configured, and that you are using the correct toolchain.

Without a more detailed error message I can't tell you much more than that.

Comment: I am using GCC/G++ 4.7. Do you need to know anything else?

Comment: You have the correct tools installed, but you need to be sure your IDE is configured properly.  Have you followed these steps?
https://netbeans.org/community/releases/73/cpp-setup-instructions.html#compilers

Comment: Yeh Netbeans is definitely using 4.7 because I originally had 4.6 and when I selected c++11 I had compiler errors- but I don't anymore because I upgraded to g++ 4.7. Therefore its definitely g++ 4.7 which is configured.

Comment: error: #error "This Intel <math.h> is for use with only the Intel compilers!"

The compiler encountered an error because a symbol required for using math had not been defined
#ifndef __THIS_IS_A_SYMBOL_THAT_SAYS_IM_AN_INTEL_MACHINE
#error "This Intel <math.h> is for use with only the Intel compilers!"
#endif

Somehow you've managed to install a math header that doesn't think it's a math header for your machine. Or your netbeans is targeted at an architecture that is not intel, and you are not using the toolchain for that architecture.