# Error with #include <ctype.h> in C program

Tags: c, netbeans, include, cygwin

I'm trying to use `isspace` and `strlen` in my code, so I used `#include <ctype.h>`. I'm getting the error: "In file included from" (doesn't say anything after 'from') on the `#include <ctype.h>` line. I'm using Netbeans and I was confused by Cygwin, so I may have made a mistake when I downloaded it. Any idea what the problem is and how I can fix it?

Also, `#include <string.h>` isn't giving me an error.

Thanks!

Comment: Would you please post the complete compiler output for that file?

Comment: Have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748546/include-cmath-in-file-included-from-error-message

Comment: probably a `-std=c99`-related problem